# Command Prompt: Set up for Python 2.7 by default

Tags: python, windows, command-prompt

My command prompt is currently running Python 3.2 by default how do I set it up to run Python 2.7 by default, I have changed the PATH variable to point towards Python 2.7, but that did not work.

---

UPDATE:

It still does not work. :(

Still running python3 - to be specific it runs python3 when I am trying to install flask - which is what I want to do.

More generally, when I simply type python into the command line, it does nothing.

I get a 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file error.

No idea what to do.

Comment: Have you reopenend your command prompt after you changed PATH?

Comment: Check you've closed any existing open prompts, and check your path by `set path` in a new one

Comment: Can you echo %PATH% and check that no other python.exe exists in path directories? Maybe running python with parameters may help locate the one you're running.

Comment: it says python 27, too bad it somehow runs python3 #confused

Comment: To be precise the last part says file://C:/Python27/Scripts/

Comment: Place the Python27 location in path as the first one, see if it helps. Run python.exe -V from Python27 location to check that it's really 2.7

Comment: And there's no mention of Python3 at all which is strange since that is what it runs

Comment: file://C:/Python27/Scripts/ seems wrong to me, should be C:/Python27/Scripts/ or C:/Python27/?

Comment: I changed it, it still doesn't work though

Comment: rename your python32 directory, and rerun python at command prompt.  I am suggesting this because you might, for some odd reason, have multiple versions of python32 installed.  If python starts up with 3.2 after you have renamed your python32 directory then something else is going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call your Python scripts directly using `python script.py` then setting the PATH to have the 2.7 directory first should be enough.

If you want to call Python scripts indirectly with the shell, i.e. by writing just `script.py` *or* by executing the file from the explorer, you need to set the 2.7 installation as the default program handler for the `.py` extension. The easiest way to do that is to run the Python installer again and choose the option “make this installation the default”.

Note that with the new [launcher](http://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher), that ships with 3.3+, you don’t need this, as you can specify the version number using a shebang line and the launcher will automatically pick the appropriate interpreter.

Comment: I get a 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file error when I say python script.py

Answer (score 1):

Changing your PATH environment variable should do the trick.  Some troubleshooting tips:

- Make sure you didn't just change the local, but rather the system variable to reflect the new location
- Make sure you restarted your CL window (aka close "cmd" or command prompt and reopen it).  This will refresh the system variables you just updated.
- Make sure you remove all references to C:\Python32\ or whatever the old path was (again, check local and system PATH - they are both found on the same environmental variables window).
- Check to see if Python3.2 is installed where you think it is... (just rename the directory to something like OLD_Python3.2 and go to your CLI and enter "python" - does it start up?  If it does is it 2.7? or 3.2?  If not, you did something wrong with your PATH variable.
- All else fails - reboot and try again (you might have some persistent environment variable - which I don't see how that can be - but hey, we are brainstorming here! - and a reboot would give you a fresh start.

If that doesn't work then I'd think you are doing something else wrong (aka user error).  CMD has to know where to look for python before it can execute.  It knows this from your PATH variable... now granted, I work almost exclusively in 2.6/2.7, so if they did something to the registry (which I doubt) then I wouldn't know about that.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Change the two las lines to you current python desired build path:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

' Extracted from Python 2.7 silent installation By Elektro H@cker

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py]
@="Python.File"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pyc]
@="Python.CompiledFile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pyo]
@="Python.CompiledFile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pyw]
@="Python.NoConFile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\Shell\Open\Command]
@="CMD /K \"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python\\Python.exe\" \"%1\" %*\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile\Shell\open\command]
@="CMD /K \"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python\\Pythonw.exe\" \"%1\" %*\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this as root:

```
$ ln -s python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Logout & login again as root:

```
$ python -V
```

It works for me, hoping the same to you.

Cheers,